# Can i get a list of models which has foreign key relation with a given model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a model. I want a list of models which have foreign key (or any) relation with my given model. please help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a `ForeignKey` relation, then Django makes a relation in reverse as well. You thus can inspect the [**`Options`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/meta/#module-django.db.models.options). We thus can obtain a list of fields with:

```
[field for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if field.is_relation]
```

you can obtain the model to which these are linked by accessing the [**`.related_model`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.related_model):

```
[field.related_model for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if field.is_relation]
```